# GTM environment equivalent for Firebase apps

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I have a project which runs Firebase and GTM on apps.

I am looking for a solution which is something similar or equivalent to GTM environments for Web containers.

What is required, What I am looking to achieve.

- use multiple containers (one for staging/test/dev/qa/beta and one for production/live) for apps or a similar
- build tags in the staging container and self test (or closed beta test) on app before pushing the new tags into the production container for apps.
- For Android I know there is something like different flavors in gradle which allows installation of different containers. However, I have not tested this approach yet. For iOS, I do not know what I can do to achieve this.

Can anyone shed some light on approaches to achieve separation between staging and production tags for Firebase apps using GTM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kenny,

Firebase remote config helps you in your case.

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-ios

You can also segment your environment(containers in GTM) by projects(in firebase term)

> ie., you can segment your environment by projects(production, stage, qa in different projects)

Hope this helps!